# formula to autofill with condition and skip blank cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, if

I have the master sheet and data sheet (more than 1 but same format)

This is the example of the data from the sheet

| Project (Column C) | Details (Column E) |
| --- | --- |
| Project A |  |
|  | Laptop |
|  | Printer |
|  | Camera |
|  |  |
| *blank* |  |
|  | Phone |
|  | Projector |
|  |  |
| Project C |  |
|  | Implementation |
|  | Debug |
|  | Smart TV |

what I need to do is to copy the project and skip the second column

if the project is blank then copy all the second column

but if the next first column contains words again, then copy and skip the second column

also, skip the blank rows and the formula able to accommodate more than one data sheets

in my case, if the C Column cell is filled, then copy the cell, but if the C Column is blank, then copy the E Column until it blanks then go back to C Column

expected outcome:

| Project (Column C) |
| --- |
| Project A |
| Phone |
| Projector |
| Project C |

the formula I use right now: `=IF('Data1'!C7<>0;'Data1'!C7;'Data1'!E7)`

the result from my formula:

| Project (Column C) |
| --- |
| Project A |
| Laptop |
| Printer |
| Camera |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| Phone |
| Projector |
| 0 |
| Project C |
| Implementation |
| Debug |
| Smart TV |

Note: the data rows are not always the same number with every data sheet (i.e. data1 100 rows, data2 400 rows, so on and I need the formula to work continuously through all the sheet (i.e. after the data from data1 finished, the formula move to data2, so on)

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have an interesting problem. Its actually two problems. The first is two reduce two columns containing text to one column, blanking out or selecting specific text. The second problem is filtering, i.e. reducing a column of data to parse out undesirable rows.

A "simple" formulae for the 1st part. Say F1 is header, F2 is the text "Discard", then F3:

```
=IF(C3&E3="",IF(E4<>"",XLOOKUP("*",$C$1:C3,$C$1:C3,"",2,-1),"Discard"),IF(C3<>"","Discard",IF(F2="Discard","Discard",C3&E3)))
```

Semantically it means this:

```
IF both fields empty then 
    If the detail field below you is also empty then 
        Cell = "Discard"  %this is truely a blank spacer row
    else
        %this is the blank row indicating the items to keep will follow
        %use XLOOKUP to search upward for the project field above you
        Cell = XLOOKUP("*",$C$1:C3,$C$1:C3,"",2,-1)
    end
else
    %One or both fields contain text         
    If project field is empty then 
        %there is something in the details field
        %but we don't know if this is from the section to discard or keep
        %so we look at the results above us, if its "discard" we discard also
        If cell in F above is "Discard" then
            %we are in a discard section
            Cell = "Discard"
        else
            %we are in a keep section
            Cell = E3
        end
    else
        %so project field is not empty, we can discard project for now
        %this "discard" will trigger rows below to also discard
        Cell = "Discard"
    end
end
```

Now for the second part, filter out all the "Discard" values using either a normal filter, or the Office 365 FILTER function:

```
=FILTER($F:F17,F1:F17<>"Discard")
```

Comment: I believe the solution you give can solve my problems, unfortunately, I use 2010 excel so xlookup is not available for my version and filter function too
Is there any other formula that can be used for 2010 version?

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately there is no "look up above you until the cell is not blank" function without xlookup. An alternative solution would be to create an extra "project" helper column with formula (say in G3) `=IF(C3="",G2,C3)`. Now the XLOOKUP part in the above formula can simply be replaced with the value in column G.

Comment: how about vba? is there any way that this can be done by vba? thanks

Comment: The easiest yet manual alternative for FILTER in older Excel versions, is simply to use the filter function on the Home ribbon (CTRL+SHIFT+L). Or you could opt for yet another help column solution. Say H1 is "Keep" then H2 `=IF(F2="Discard",0,1)`. This gives you a column of ones to search into for values to keep.  Now in I1 put 0 and I2 put `=MATCH(1,INDEX($H$2:$H$1000,I1+1):$H$1000,0)+I2`, which creates a running index to the ones to keep only. In J2 `=INDEX($I$2:$I$1000,I2)`. That, or find as super complicated array formula on the web too :)

Comment: The two formulae in the comments should have you covered in Excel 2010, without requiring VBA. Kindly do checkmark the solution if you consider this problem solved.

Comment: I see thanks for the improvement